How to make sure if my car has a tow package?
I have bought a used 2008 Highlander Sport. I guess it has a tow package installed as I see the tool in back of the car but I am not sure if it is a OEM or aftermarket. How can I make sure about it?
PS: I am asking because I want to replace the alternator but know should I buy 130Amp as 150Amp is for cars with tow package.

The alternator itself should have the amperage rating on it. To me, if they are both the same size physically and have the same mounting bosses, you cannot go wrong with the higher rated alternator. While it would cost more than the 130A, the 150A won't cause any issues if it's a direct fit.

Exactly what is included in a 'tow package' varies, but you should look for things like the transmission radiator up front, a place to plug a tow brake controller into (driver side footwell in my 2018 Tacoma), and the 4/7 pin trailer plug for brakes/lights for the trailer.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: Doesn't increase the gas consumption?

@best_of_man - It would be slight if any. Mainly, a 150A alternator can provide up to that amount of amperage ... doesn't mean it's going to provide that at all times. When draw is light electrically, then the drag is correspondingly going to be light.

@best_of_man the bigger capacity alternator doesn't change the power demand, which is the electrical power that you are using.

@WeatherVane: Yeah but I was thinking about more gas consumption or more pressure on the engine

Consider an electric hedge trimmer available as 300 watt and 500 watt versions. The larger is more powerful and uses more power. But an alternator isn't using power. It provides it, and the larger rating means it can supply more power, if needed by the demands of the vehicle's equipment. You'll get more gas consumption, but only when there is that power demand, which the smaller rated alternator is inadequate for.

Why should it make a difference whether the tow package is aftermarket or OEM?

@WeatherVane - Because if it had one installed from the factory, it comes with a bigger (150A v 130A) alternator. If it's aftermarket, it wouldn't have that ... it would only have the hitch. It's actually the alternator they need to change, but doesn't know which one to get. This is their way of understanding which alternator to get to replace their defunct one.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I wonder if the aftermarket package uprates components in the vehicle itself? The factory package seems to have better cooling capacity for various fluids, which may require more power, even if the actual tow is not installed.

A reddit post says Typically the "Tow Package" does not include a tow bar or even wiring. There may be extra brackets in the rear to attach a tow bar to but it's usually a slightly bigger alternator, a slightly bigger radiator (only abut 8floz more in the Highlander) and a transmission cooler. You can tell if it has the tow package by looking for the transmission cooler in the very lower section of the grill on the drivers side. You should be able to see radiator fins visible.

@WeatherVane - Well, that doesn't negate my point. When you put a tow bar on your vehicle, it's usually just the tow bar. As far as what's included from the factory, it depends on the manufacturer. My Silverado came with a tow package which included the receiver in the back as well as a built in trailer brake and a 7-pin socket to wire it.
